# Disadvantage of setting html through jquery html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

is there any disadvantage on setting html of say for example the content of a div through jqyuery's `html()` function?

Because I have a static content inside a `div`, it is a progress bar which is made by `<li>`. Now, it displays perfectly fine, each bar has its gap with each other, with a click of a button its contents will be change but all same code, but now it doesnt displays like before. It displays as a continuous line, no more gaps between `<li>`.

Any idea?

Code:

```
<div id="branch-status-bar-container">
  <ol class="branch-status-bar" data-branch-status-bar-steps="8" >
    <li class="branch-status-bar-done" id="" > </li>
    <li class="branch-status-bar-done" id="" > </li>
    <li class="branch-status-bar-done" id="" > </li>
    <li class="branch-status-bar-done" id="" > </li>
    <li class="branch-status-bar-done" id="" > </li>
    <li class="branch-status-bar-done" id="" > </li>
    <li class="branch-status-bar-done" id="" > </li>
    <li class="branch-status-bar-done" id="" > </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#branch-status-bar-container {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.branch-status-bar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.branch-status-bar li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 3em;
}

.branch-status-bar[branch-data-status-bar-steps="2"] li {
    width: 49%;
}

.branch-status-bar[branch-data-status-bar-steps="3"] li {
    width: 33%;
}

.branch-status-bar[branch-data-status-bar-steps="4"] li {
    width: 24%;
}

.branch-status-bar[branch-data-status-bar-steps="5"] li {
    width: 19%;
}

.branch-status-bar[branch-data-status-bar-steps="6"] li {
    width: 16%;
}

.branch-status-bar[branch-data-status-bar-steps="7"] li {
    width: 14%;
}

.branch-status-bar[branch-data-status-bar-steps="8"] li {
.branch-status-bar[branch-data-status-bar-steps="9"] li {
    width: 11%;
}

.branch-status-bar li.branch-status-bar-done {
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 14px solid #0489B1;
    width: 12%;
}

.branch-status-bar li:after {
    content: "\00a0\00a0";
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#profit-centers').on('change', function (){
        var profit_center_id = $('#profit-centers').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/reporting-portal/get-profit-center',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                profit_center_id : profit_center_id
            }, 
            success: function (data) {
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                var html = profit_center.branch(json);
                $('#profit-center-content').html(html);
            }, 
            error: function () {

            }  
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show us your code. Code is worth 1000 words.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your `CSS`.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the response from the your json post? And the profit_center.branch code so that we can see what html you're setting into your div?

Answer (score 0):

```
.branch-status-bar li:after {
    content: "\00a0\00a0";
    line-height: 3em;
}
```

maybe you could try that if content is changing to abnormal after click of button.